# SSIS derived column for the case condition doesn't show the exact results as needed

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, expression, etl

I am this case conditional expression as a derived column, the result i not as expected

```
(DT_STR,255,1252)((Step1_Emc_stg_Heading >= "315" && Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= "45") ? "Northbound"
: (Step1_Emc_stg_Heading >= "46" && Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= "135") ? "Eastbound"
: (Step1_Emc_stg_Heading >= "136" && Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= "225") ? "Southbound" 
: (Step1_Emc_stg_Heading >= "226" && Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= "314") ? "Westbound" : "Nobound")
```

Comment: Before asking your first question, it is recommended to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com) to learn more about asking good questions, accepting answers and other website rules. Also to get your the *"informed"* badge.

Comment: Your biggest issue here is assuming string values can be evaluated the same as numbers. for example, "6">"315244542" evaluates as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in the first case

```
Step1_Emc_stg_Heading >= "315" && Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= "45"
```

you have to replace `45` with a number bigger than `315` or you have to use logical OR `||` instead or logical And `&&`

```
Step1_Emc_stg_Heading >= "315" || Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= "45"
```

## Update 1

Try the following expression (use numbers instead of string, and reorder conditions):

```
(DT_STR,255,1252)((DT_I4)Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= 45 ? "Northbound"
:  (DT_I4)Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= 135 ? "Eastbound"
:  (DT_I4)Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= 225 ? "Southbound" 
:  (DT_I4)Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= 314 ? "Westbound" 
:  (DT_I4)Step1_Emc_stg_Heading >= 315 ? "Northbound" : "Nobound")
```

Comment: the first class i need like column value more than 315 and the same column less than 45 can you help me building the statement

Comment: I was using the Step1_Emc_stg_Heading >= "315" || Step1_Emc_stg_Heading <= "45" before but it's not going to the other case statements and returning all columns as 'Northbound'

Comment: This worked exactly and i could have changed to the 4 bite signed integer and thanks for the wonderful tip @hadi

Comment: @manojyadla ur welcome :). If my answer solved the issue you have to accept it. Just check the mark at the left of the answer.

Comment: I know this is solved but a future developer following up on this would probably rather see a c# switch statement in a script component with comments

Comment: Also couldn't you remove the left side of the && as you already checked for that in the prior if?

Comment: @KeithL i agree with that, the left side of && can be removed (i edited my answer).